# How do I load an LCR image from my server using AlamofireImage?

Tags: alamofire, tvos

I'm trying to load an LCR image for use as a collection view cell image using AlamofireImage but nothing is showing up.

```
cell.imageView.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/MY_LCR_IMAGE.lcr")!)
```

If I use `https://placehold.it/500x500` as the URL string (a PNG), it works. And the same LCR file, loads fine in my TVML/TVJS app. So I know the problem is not the LCR file or generally with how I'm attempting to load the image using `af_setImageWithURL`.

I'm guessing that I need to support the correct MIME type for an LCR image. When I check the MIME type of my LCR file, it is `application/octet-stream`. The AlamofireImage documentation says:

> If the image you are attempting to download is an invalid MIME type
>   not in the list, you can add custom acceptable content types using the
>   addAcceptableImageContentTypes extension on the Request type.

So I've included the following line before I attempt to call `af_setImageWithURL`.

```
Request.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(["application/octet-stream"])
```

I still end up with no images.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in AlamofireImage that it wasn't using the acceptableImageContentTypes for af_setImageWithURL. AlamofireImage 2.2.0 fixes that.